# Pycaret, ROC曲線作成時のPlot_modelの時に、ROC＿AUCが下がることについて

Tags: python, 機械学習

よろしくお願い申し上げます。
Pycaretを使用し、機械学習を行い、ROC曲線を記載すると、その前の図とAUCが大きく異なります。
何か問題があるのでしょうか？
何卒よろしくお願い申し上げます。[image: 左：10foldのAUC。これのMeanがROC曲線に反映されるといいのですが、右：AUC低い！]

環境：Googlecolab

Comment: どういうことについて知りたいのかをはっきりさせるため、知りたい問題をより具体的にしたり、追加の詳細を書き加えたりしてください。現状のままだと何についての質問なのかが分かりづらいです。

Comment: 左のMeanAUC値は0.8と表示されてますが、右のROC曲線のAUC値は0.4などと表示されており、乖離しております。0.8のROC曲線を記載する方法はありますか？